# const int and const char* (Why use a pointer?)

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am a beginner to c++. The below code snippet is taken from a program for parsing text input.

```
const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512;
const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20;
const char* const DELIMITER = ",";
```

I couldn't find a reason for why the programmer used 
**const pointer** 
for variable DELIMITER, as he didn't use const pointer for other variables. Please clarify.

Comment: Have you looked at the point where the constants are used? I suspect there is a function used somewhere that expects a string (to support several delimiter characters).

Comment: For people not bothering to read this question properly: OP is asking why `const int` **no pointer** whereas `const char` **uses pointer**.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is a dup question. I just haven't found it. `const char*` is the 'old' way to represent a string. You'll notice that the value is also initialised as a string using double quotes instead of single quotes if it were a regular char: `const char c = ',';` This search should give you lots of reading material: [c++ const char*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+const+char*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`512` and `20` are constants of type `int`. Their values can be stored in objects (variables) of type `int`. There's no need for pointers.

A string literal like `","` is not a simple scalar value. It's of type `const char[2]`, an array of two `char`s. (`const` means read-only.)

Though arrays and pointers are very different things (and don't let anyone tell you otherwise!), arrays in C and C++ are most commonly manipulated via pointers to their elements. Thus a `char*` pointer can be used to, for example, traverse a string and provide access to each of its elements.

The extra `const` means that the pointer itself cannot be modified.

Comment: "and don't let anyone tell you otherwise!" - +1 for making the point